# Firebase hosting rest API Patch headers

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-hosting

Based on the firebase hosting documentation, I'm trying to update the header configuration (without having to redeploy everything, which is important in my case).

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/hosting/rest/v1beta1/sites.versions/patch

However, I can't do it, I always get an error.

Here's the URL
`https://firebasehosting.googleapis.com/v1beta1/sites/SITE_NAME/versions/VERSION_ID?updateMask=config`

Here's the body of my request:

```json
{
    "config": {
        "headers": [
            {
              "headers": {
                "Content-Security-Policy": "frame-src https://...
              },
              "glob": "**/*"
            }
          ]
    }
}
```

The response:

```json
{
    "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
        "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
    }
}
```

Note that when I try to modify the labels (for example), it works.

```json
{
    "labels": {
        "foo":"bar"
    }
}
```

Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

can you try

```
{
    "config": {
        "headers": [
            {
                "Content-Security-Policy": "frame-src https://...",
                "glob": "**/*"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

insted of

```
{
    "config": {
        "headers": [
            {
              "headers": {
                "Content-Security-Policy": "frame-src https://...
              },
              "glob": "**/*"
            }
          ]
    }
}
```